# Custom UUID for bluetooth using bluez

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to pair my iPhone with my ubuntu computer over bluetooth. I'd like to use CoreBluetooth. I have bluez configured correctly, but I need a UUID for CoreBluetooth to connect to my computer. How do I go about setting a custom UUID in bluez?

Ultimately, I'd like to send commands with my iPhone to my pc and then use https://github.com/eelcocramer/node-bluetooth-serial-port to access the transferred data. Is there a better way to do this? I'm new to bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Does your computer supports bluetooth 4.0? You can search for

```
[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
```

and every reachable device will be found.
With your other problem i can't help you sry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use bluetooth classic not the low energy for serial port communication